# Nodejs EventEmitter & load balancing

Tags: node.js, load-balancing, eventemitter

I heard someone says
'EventEmitter becomes an issue the moment you decide to load balance. I haven’t used it in 4 or 5 years because I’m always clustering my Node apps'

Is there a relationship between 'EventEmitter' and 'load balance'?
Is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be confused about something.  An `EventEmitter` is just a tool used for letting people subscribe to notifications/events and for sending notifications/events to the subscribers of that particular event.  Lots and lots of node.js objects use `EventEmitters and its interface.  It really has nothing to do with load balancing.

For example, an [HTTP request object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest), an HTTP server and a socket object are all derived from an EventEmitter.  So, lots of things you would do in node.js use EventEmitters all the time.

> Is there a relationship between 'EventEmitter' and 'load balance'?

No, there is not.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I just want to make sure.